# Adams-Bashforth for Second order ODE IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let's say we're given the following set of information:
\begin{cases} y''(x)-2y'(x)+2 \sin(x) \, y(x)=3x^2\\y(0)=0\\y'(0)=0\end{cases}
The task at hand is to implement the Adams-Bashforth method (e.g. AB2) to calculate $y(x)$ in an arbitrary interval $h$, **without reducing its order** - i.e. *reducing $y''(x)$ to first order as per $v(x)=y'(x)$ does not fit the bill* (as any other way different from **applying AB**). AB would have to solve this IVP *without* dealing with $y'(x)$, having to be applied at $y''(x)$.

My problem with this question is the only way I've seen AB being applied is in first order ODEs. I wouldn't have a single issue with this particular case if it was one of those, since I could apply Euler's method to get $y(1)$ and just use AB in a loop for the rest of times.

I have searched thoroughly online and in books of mine, but couldn't find a single adaptation of AB for this particular case - even doubted there was one, but my mentor guaranteed the adaptation exists.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: $sen(x)=\sin(x)$?

Comment: @mickep yeah, thank you for pointing it out. Here in Brazil "seno" means "sin".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not reduce its order. You transform the second order equation to the equivalent system of two equations of the first order:

z'(x)-2z(x)+2sen(x)y(x)=3x^2

y'(x)=z(x)

y(0)=0

z(0)=0

Then you can apply your numerical method to the system of the first order.